# Can't Save Notification Data to SQLite DB from OneSignal

Tags: android, sqlite, push-notification, onesignal

Unable to save data to Database on android device from OneSignal Handler Class that extends Application Class.

How to save data received in notification to Database in my **NotificationReceivedHandler**. I am getting database instance as follows::

```
SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Also, how to handle opening of notification when the device is in foreground, as in that case, the notification is shown as an Alert Dialog. So, how do I detect if the notification was opened from foreground of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your SQLite question.

> Also, how to handle opening of notification when the device is in
>   foreground, as in that case, the notification is shown as an Alert
>   Dialog. So, how do I detect if the notification was opened from
>   foreground of the app?

The [OSNotification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--osnotification-) instance sent to [NotificationReceivedHandler](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section-receiving-notifications) will have an isAppInFocus attribute that you can use to detect this.

Comment: Solved the SQLite part. It was a totally unrelated bug, a JSON parsing error.